# Binding an XElement to BindingSource c#

Tags: winforms, datagridview, linq-to-xml, bindingsource

I am reading some xml and I was wondering if is possible to bind an XElement to a binding Source
and bind the binding source to a datagriview winforms.

I have tried all sorts but no success.

Each Element within this Xelement must create a data row within datagridview

any snippets or suggestions?

thanks

Edit

I am trying to build a datatable to bind to a datagridView
Tried as follows

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //at runtime could be any object
        const string testXElement = @"<MyObject xmlns=""http://www.test.com/"">
          <code>Test</code>
          <Date>2012-06-24T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
          <Name>John</Name>
        </MyObject>";
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(testXElement);
        var dgv=new DataGridView();

        //Build dataTable from it or 
        var dt=new DataTable();
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.test.com/";
        foreach (var x in element.Descendants(ns + "MyObject").Elements())
        {
            var dc = new DataColumn {ColumnName = x.Name.ToString()};
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            //row[dc] = );
        }
        dgv.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this help. Updated the answer. Each element creates a row in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//at runtime could be any object
            const string testXElement = @"<MyObject xmlns=""http://www.test.com/"">
                                            <code>Test</code>
                                            <Date>2012-06-24T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
                                            <Name>John</Name>
                                         </MyObject>";
            XElement element = XElement.Parse(testXElement); 


            var temp = from obj in element.Elements() 
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = obj.Name.LocalName,
                           Value = obj.Value
                       };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = temp.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply.My only trouble is that I only know the object at runtime.I was planning to convert an xelement and loop through it to a datatable and bind the datatable.Cannot seem to be able to loop through xelement EG <MyObject xmlns="http://www.test.com/">
  <code>Test</code>
  <Date>2012-06-24T00:00:00+01:00</Date>
  <Name>John</Name>
</MyObject>

Comment: If you are `directly` getting an `XElement`, then you can use something like  `xElement.Elements(<<your namespace>> + "MyObject")`

Comment: If you can post the code i.e. what you have tried so far then may be we can reach some conclusion.

Comment: Updated with a code example that I cannot seem to build.thanks for your help Agarwal